# Having trouble visualising trigonometry questions

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

The angle of depression from the top of an 8 m tree down to a rabbit is[image]. If an eagle is perched in the top of the tree, how far does it need to fly to reach the rabbit, to the nearest metre?

The answer is 12m, and I don't even know what this question is trying to visually convey to me.

Comment: Have you tried drawing the tree? Don't include the leaves, they get in the way. But seriously, draw the tree, eagle and rabbit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint**

Consider that the tree is an isoceles triangle, so one side of the tree is a right triangle. You know the angle $(43.52°)$ and the height $(8$ meters). Try to remember the trigonometric function which relates the hypothenuse and the adjacent side.

I am sure that you can take from here.